# Updating Date object to now()

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, garbage-collection

I need to read the current time in one second intervals.
Should I rely on garbage collection to take care of regularly created instances of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) like `mytime = new Date()` or should I update `mytime` with the static [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) - and how?

---

Put differently:

```
let mytime = new Date();
...
// regularly
// A)
mytime = new Date(); // replace with current instance, rely on garbage collection
// OR
// B)
mytime.setUTCMilliseconds(Date.now()); // update original instance
```

Comment: mytime will be the time when Date.now() was called - it doesn't update itself

Comment: @Bravo Not sure what you are saying. `mytime` was instanciated once and then should be updated regularly.`Date.now()` returns ms since since "January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC", so `mytime` probably could be updated with `mytime.setUTCMilliseconds(Date.now())`?

Comment: no, mytime doesn't change unless you change it ... but ... you've shown naff all code, so ... who knows what mytime is

Comment: @Bravo Added code hoping to clear up the misunderstanding...

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://javascript.info/garbage-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless for some reason you need to make sure that you have only a single shared instance and that it gets mutated (hint: you really shouldn't), just create new date objects whenever you need them. GC will take care of the old ones just fine.

Comment: jsbench.me reports for my computer that this is 8% faster.